# CodenameOne Changing font size (lumia)

Tags: java, codenameone

The following code doesn't give an exception under iOS, however it gives a nullpointer exception under the Lumia skin. I am wondering how I can change the fontsize under Windows Phone.

```
    score = new Label("Score");
    score.getStyle().getFont().derive(50, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't really do anything. Font can be null so you will get that exception, however since derive just generates a new font object which you aren't putting anywhere this won't do anything.

You are also using `getStyle()` which will work in the case of Label but you should normally use `getUnselectedStyle()/getSelectedStyle()`.

To increase font size define a TTF file in the designer and define its size for a specific UIID then use the `setUIID` method to define the style for the component.